# Some tokens show as "missing name or description" in status report

Tags: 7, tokens

Looking at a Drupal 7.43 maintenance project, my status report lists the following issue for Token 7.x-1.6:

```
The following tokens or token types are missing required name and/or description information:

$info['types']['date']
$info['tokens']['node']['url']
$info['tokens']['file']['size']
$info['tokens']['user']['url']
$info['tokens']['date']['custom']
The following token types are not defined but have tokens:

$info['types']['node']
$info['types']['term']
$info['types']['vocabulary']
$info['types']['file']
$info['types']['user']
$info['types']['current-user']
```

I have cleared cache a few times, hit update.php, and ran cron a handful of times. This message never goes away.

It is causing RealName to no longer work, path aliases are not being made, and page title / meta tags are not appearing (all are driven by Token).

What is causing this and how can I fix it? I am unable to replicate the issue locally with the same database and same code.

Comment: Did you check you aren't missing some Drupal core files? As far as I can see, [`node_token_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tokens.inc/function/node_token_info/7.x) does define _node_ as token type (`'types' => array('node' => $type)`). Otherwise, there is a module implementing `hook_token_info_alter()` that is messing up things.

Comment: Yeah, it's all there. I don't see any shenanigans with hook_token_info_alter in contrib or custom modules.

Comment: A suggestion. Run the Hacked module and check if some file has been modified.

Comment: According to https://www.drupal.org/node/2256315, entity_tokens or the workflow module can cause problem.

Comment: @Kevin Did you find the solution for this ? 
Tokens or token types missing name property
$info['types']['date']
$info['tokens']['node']['url']
$info['tokens']['file']['size']
$info['tokens']['user']['url']
$info['tokens']['date']['custom']

Please share your solution.

Thank you

Comment: Increased opcache memory from 64 to 128 M

Answer (score 0):

In *my* case, the answer is related to the autoslave module: https://www.drupal.org/node/2898888

Also discussed here (not resolved), https://www.drupal.org/node/1265848#comment-12191146

Other mentions online about the PHP memory settings had no effect for me.

Hopefully this helps someone as the issue has been quite elusive.